# Скопировать текст из сайта в Memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

**Текстовый файл Text.txt расположен на сайте и в нем текст:**

```
Год:2020
Число:19
Месяц:09
```

**Делаю запрос вот так:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Lines.Add(IdHTTP1.Get('http://test.ru/text.txt'));
end;
```

**И проблема в том что в Мемо текст получаю в одну строчку:**

```
Год:2020Число:19Месяц:09
```

**А должен быть текст в Memo в столбик как и в текстовом файле. Что делаю не так ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принятой через `Get` строчке есть переводы строк, или они уже потеряны?

Если есть, то

```
Memo1.Lines.DelimitedText := IdHTTP1.Get...c
```

с предварительной установкой соответствующего `Delimiter`

Comment: Спасибо все заработало.